# Implement compareTo in terms of equals and hashcode

Tags: java, collections, compare

Is it a bad idea (could there be consequences I overlooked) to do implement compare to using equals and hashcode?  I don't care about the ordering of the elements i just need the sorting to be deterministic. This is of course assuming that my equals and hashcode are correct.

Here is what my compareTo looks like

```
@Override
public int compareTo(DividendEvent other) {
    final int BEFORE = -1;
    final int EQUAL = 0;
    final int AFTER = 1;

    if(other == null){
        return BEFORE;
    }
    else if (this.equals(other)){
        return EQUAL;
    }
    else if (this.hashCode()>other.hashCode()){
        return AFTER;
    }
    else{
        return BEFORE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you implement your `hashCode` method to take into account some kind of ordering?

Comment: Is there really not a better property to use for comparing than hashcode?

Comment: Bad idea - `equals` is fine, but `hashCode` is not guaranteed nor expected to be unique, it's just for 'bucketing'. Even if you implemented it to be unique, it wouldn't serve as a good hashCode anymore.

Comment: It's not wrong, but why would you want to do something like this? This is only useful for ordering your objects by their hashCode... I don't see any value in that

Comment: I need to them ordered but dont really care what the order is. If i recreate the List i'm stuffing these objects in i need to compare to what the previous value was so they need to be sorted before comparing the lists.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using lombok to generate the hashcode

Comment: I don't think lombok uses any ordering. What are you trying to achieve with `this.hashCode()>other.hashCode()`? What's the meaning behind that statement?

Comment: @Kayaman There are 15 + fields in this class and I have no guarantee of any of them being nonnull so no there is no good single property to use.

Comment: It is wrong, because two objects that are not equal may still return the same hashCode, and your code returns `BEFORE` is that case, meaning that `a.compareTo(b)` and `b.compareTo(a)` return inconsistent results.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't understand what you mean by hashcode returning some sort of ordering? and 'this.hashCode()>other.hashCode()' is just a way to force them into an order....Unless there is a collision on the hashcode it would work.

Comment: If you can compare 15+ fields for the `equals()` implementation and combine the 15+ hashcodes for the `hashCode()` implementation, why can't you compare 15+ fields for the `compareTo()` implementation? Or are you just being lazy?

Comment: @Andreas Yes I'm being lazy :) .  Equals and hashCode are being generated by lombok. So why not take advantage of them if possible?

Comment: Well, sorry, you can't. Since `hashCode()` is not guaranteed to be unique for un-equal objects, `compareTo()` will either return arbitrary `BEFORE` or `AFTER` value (as currently coded), or `EQUAL` (if code fixed, as allowed for "inconsistent with equals"), and sorting will be arbitrary in either case, not meeting your goal of deterministic sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What matters to avoid "weird things" is to comply with [the contract of `compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-), namely:

- `sgn(x.compareTo(y)) == -sgn(y.compareTo(x))`
- `(x.compareTo(y)>0 && y.compareTo(z)>0)` implies `x.compareTo(z)>0`
- `x.compareTo(y)==0` implies that `sgn(x.compareTo(z)) == sgn(y.compareTo(z))` for all `z`

Your implementation does not tick the first box for objects that are not equal but have the same hashcode.

You could amend it like:

```
else if (this.equals(other) || this.hashCode() == other.hashCode()){
```

to tick the three boxes. Your implementation will then become inconsistent with equals but apart from that it will look fine.

That assumes that your `hashCode` is constant for a given object.

Comment: Being "inconsistent with equals" means that two different (not equal) objects may be ordered equal, which means that they retain original order in a `sort()`. In that case, the goal of deterministic sorting will only be true if original order is deterministic, and if that was the case, there'd be no need for all this, so: Still not deterministic. Solution not viable.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I'll bear the risk of the collision as the result of one happening is a 50%(ish) chance of an empty entry in an audit table...

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a framework requires you to override .equals() in order to work, (I encountered this in jsf+ejb), and that type of implementation needs equality check in terms of an object ID. When you implement compareTo that way, and your logic of "comparing" objects is different than that, this leads to confusion.

If those classes are your domain objects and you are not using them in other layers, it maybe OK. I just think that .equals method indicate equality in a technical manner (such as same database id), and some other method like .identical(), which you implement yourself, in a business-logic manner.